# LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence in R Sweave

Tags: r, latex, pdflatex, sweave

I'm new using Sweave in R. All guides I've seen begin trying to compile to PDF the simplest document (code below):

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\title{My title}
\author{Some text with accent, e.g. í}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The problem is that this doesn't work directly for me. I receive the following error message:

```
Error: LaTeX failed to compile C:/Users/V1/Desktop/Projects/Projects2/teste.tex. 
See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.
Execução interrompida
failed

Error: teste.tex:12: LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence (�\endtabular).
Error: teste.tex:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The issue appears to be encoding related. I've tried `% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`without success. **The solution that worked was use `% \UseRawInputEncoding`** at the beginning.

My questions are: why did this happen? Is it safe to continue builduing the document? What am I supposed to do to obtain the desired result without putting this line code at the beginning? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A likely cause is that you saved the file in some encoding other than UTF-8.  Which editor did you use to save it?  Does it offer an option to change the encoding?

Comment: @user2554330 I'm using RStudio and MikTex. I forgot to say but I've tried to change RStudio's encoding to UTF-8 but the error persisted.

Comment: Cam you switch to an unicode aware engine like lualatex or xelatex? Rstudio should have a dropdown in the preferences where you can switch the engine for sweave

Comment: The other possibility is to use `knitr` instead of `Sweave()`.  RStudio is written to work with it, so will probably handle the encoding automatically.  You can use `knitr`'s `.Rnw` format which is very similar to Sweave (but not the same), or switch to R Markdown.

Comment: @user2554330 Yeah, I'm definitely considering it from now on. Thank you!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I changed to xelatex as you recommended. It compiled but without the letter with accent (just disappeared in the final PDF doc)!

Comment: You would need to use a font which has this letter.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz More precisely what I meant in the previous comment was that the author's part _Some text with accent, e.g. í_ became to _Some text with accent, e.g._ in the compiled doc. Would be quite strange in this case because I think **í** is a common letter in almost all fonts - including the default font I'm using! What's driving me crazy is the fact that this problem probably shouldn't occur, that is, I shouldn't supplement the code for the compilation to work - so probably something is wrong with my default settings compared to common users.